# Active Directory (Onpremises) user login on ubuntu vm in GCP

Tags: ubuntu, active-directory, google-cloud-platform

I have Active Directory Domain Services running on Windows 2016 VMs in GCP. I tried to join one ubuntu 20.x vm (gcp) to the domain and it was successful. When I run realm list command it shows domain and all other params as expected. However, when I try to SSH to the vm using putty it keeps saying access denied. Auth.log shows: Failed password for invalid user abcdef from x.x.x.x port 51451 ssh2. I have followed the steps as per https://computingforgeeks.com/join-ubuntu-debian-to-active-directory-ad-domain
This works well for OnPremises or Azure vm (ubuntu) but not on GCP vm.
I have enabled local login from GCP console and SSH (putty) works for a local user (non AD) created with adduser cmd.
All the config steps were performed from ssh via GCP web console.

Please suggest guide... Required logs:
/var/log/sssd/sssd.log

```
NO LOGS FOR LOCAL AND ACTIVE DIRECTORY DOMAIN USER IN SSSD
```

/var/log/auth.log FOR LOCAL USER - testuser1:

```
Oct  4 09:08:27 testlinuxgcp5 sshd[1816]: Accepted password for testuser1 from x.x.x.x port 59023 ssh2
/var/log/auth.log FOR ACTIVE DIRECTORY DOMAIN USER - domainuser1:
Oct  4 09:11:00 testlinuxgcp5 sshd[1862]: Failed password for domainuser1 from x.x.x.x port 59424 ssh2
Oct  4 09:11:12 testlinuxgcp5 sshd[1864]: Invalid user domainuser1@corp.mydomain.com from x.x.x.x port 59463
Oct  4 09:11:15 testlinuxgcp5 sshd[1864]: error: Could not get shadow information for NOUSER
Oct  4 09:11:15 testlinuxgcp5 sshd[1864]: Failed password for invalid user domainuser1@corp.mydomain.com from x.x.x.x port 59463 ssh2
root@testlinuxgcp5:~# realm list
corp.mydomain.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: CORP.MYDOMAIN.COM
  domain-name: corp.mydomain.com
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: sssd-tools
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: libnss-sss
  required-package: libpam-sss
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common-bin
  login-formats: %U
  login-policy: allow-permitted-logins
  permitted-logins: domainuser1
  permitted-groups:
root@testlinuxgcp5:~#
```

Comment: You need to include the results of your test with the account and a non-SSH logon (local console).

Comment: @GregAskew - I have added the logs in my query... Thanks